# docx conversion to pdf in korean font

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, docx4j

Hope someone can help me. It's about docx to pdf conversion having korean sign in docx document.
I'm able to convert a docx document to pdf with docx4j.

In pdf document, I can see the result. But if my docx document contains korean font, I can't see any korean font in my pdf document except the latin numbers.
What do I have to do to get korean font in my pdf from the docx document?

Here is my code:

```
File docXFile ="E:/contract2Files/test.docx";
WordprocessingMLPackage wordprocessingMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(docXFile);
String   out = docXFile .replace("docx","pdf");
File pdfFile = new File(out);
OutputStream pdfFileOs = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.PdfConversion c = new JanoPdfConversion(wordprocessingMLPackage);
c.output(pdfFileOs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-3_0-beta2.zip   **(link updated 15 Nov)**

You might need to configure your font mapper, though things work out of the box with the Identity mapper on my Windows box, since I have the relevant font installed.

If this doesn't help, please put a sample docx somewhere StackOverflow users can see it.

Comment: Hello Jason,thank for your time. How can I put my korean docx document in stackoverflow so  you can have a look at it?

Comment: Hello again. there must be a possibility to tell docx, that the encoding shoulb be korean, or so? it that the right approach?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-stack-overflow-post

Comment: Encoding etc should already be taken care of.  Unzip the docx, and look at document.xml to see.

Comment: Hi Jason, here can you download my generated docx http://www.janolaw.de/export/livingwill.docx and here is my generated pdf from docx http://www.janolaw.de/export/livingwill.pdf THANKS

Comment: Jason, can you please tell me the verion of the jar you recommanded ? http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-nightly-20131008.jar ??

Answer (score 0):

thanks again. I tried the newest jar file with this code passage and it worked!!! Now I get the korean letters into pdf. Thank again.

> ThemePart themePart =
>   wordprocessingMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getThemePart();
>               org.docx4j.dml.BaseStyles.FontScheme fontScheme = themePart.getFontScheme();
>               org.docx4j.dml.TextFont textFont = fontScheme.getMinorFont().getLatin();
>               textFont.setTypeface("Malgun Gothic");